# ¿Cómo recorrer objetos desde Fetch API Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, api

Necesito consumir una **API** que saque en **Laravel** pero me da error en *consola*. No se como acceder a los datos correctamente.

```
fetch('http://tiendavirtual.com:8080/api/productos')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(datos => {
        for(let i of datos){
            console.log(i.Producto);
        }
    });
```

**Error en Consola:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**API:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es la **API** que deseo consumir en **Fetch**

Comment: Lee de nuevo el error: "Datos no es iterable". Eso significa que no es una colección (array), sino un objeto normal... como se puede ver en tu captura de pantalla. Pero como también se puede ver en tu captura, datos tiene una propiedad llamada "productos" que empieza por `[`, es decir, es un array... y es iterable

Comment: Si si ya lo arreglé, no sabia como acceder a los datos correctamente...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estas tratando de iterar la respuesta completa que te da la API, cuando tendrías que iterar solo la parte de "productos".
Es decir, a vos te dan un objeto que no es iterable desde la API, lo que tenes que hacer es en ves de iterar el objeto completo que te dan, es iterar solo la parte de "productos" que es un array. Por si no te quedo claro:

```
fetch('http://tiendavirtual.com:8080/api/productos')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(datos => {
    for(let i of datos["productos"]){
        console.log(i.Producto);
    }
});
```

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: No lo tomes a mal, pero hago la siguiente acotación: en JS se usa el término *objeto* y no *diccionario*, si usas `typeof datos` el resultado será `object`. Lo mismo sucede con *lista*. Python sí tiene una clase llamada `dict` a la cual nos referimos como *diccionario* y una clase llamada `list` a la cual nos referimos como *lista*. Siendo esta una pregunta de Javascript, me parece que debemos usar los términos adecuados del lenguaje. Esto sólo es una sugerencia, ya que la respuesta no sólo es para el OP, sino para todos los que la lean posteriormente. Saludos

Comment: En Javascript no existen los diccionarios ni las listas, existen objetos y arrays. Ver [esto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures).

Comment: Tienen razón! Disculpas por la terminología, ahora lo arreglo

Comment: Si, si me funciono perfectamente @vschiaffino, gracias... se entendió bien la explicación que distes.